# Mystery definition of exp() included with Visual C++

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019

Observed on Microsoft Visual Studio 2019.
Unsure if other versions are equally affected.

Consider this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const double frac = -1.0;
    printf("%f\n", (double)exp(frac));
}
```

By all rights, this code should not compile. Or so one would think. It's missing the math.h header.
It certainly does not compile [on gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/EaYhes75Y).
Yet, on Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 it seemingly does.

But, this mystery version of `exp()` returns unexpected results.
`exp(-1.0)` should be returning 0.3678, yet it returns 36.
`exp(-0.61)` should be returning 0.5433, yet it returns 8.

To fix this, I simply add `#include <math.h>` as I should have done in the first place.

So my question is: what definition of `exp()` does the Microsoft compiler find when the code omits to include math.h?

note:
What may provide a clue here is that this mystery definition seemingly returns an integer. The cast in the above snippet appears redundant, yet removing it reveals that `printf()` gets an integer where it expects a floating point.

Comment: Without a function prototype for `exp` it assumed `int` types. Please don't ignore the compiler warnings and then ask why it misbehaves. *warning C4013: 'exp' undefined; assuming extern returning int*. It won't magically convert that bit pattern to `double`.

Comment: Casting the return value of something isn't going to "fix" anything when the compiler thinks the data is something else entirely

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages. Pick one and stick with it. You tag your question with `C` bit you link to code compiled with a C++ compiler.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI since at least v.14  (2015) MSVC is also a C compiler, it uses file extension as guideline

Comment: If you're curious you can look at the assembly of the two program units to see what they're doing.

Comment: Visual studio 2005 prints 0.367879 for your sample program.  It compiles without #including math.h and additionally -- and interestingly -- does not complain that exp() is not defined, even with warnings cranked up max.

Comment: It definitely compiles in GCC in C mode https://godbolt.org/z/njq4Y3s9d and same to Clang https://godbolt.org/z/rfjo45eTP

Comment: @WeatherVane you are correct. I seem to not get this warning on the default warning levels. Needs `-W3` as a minimum. Which - by all accounts - I should have used.

Comment: I use -W3 generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including or not including the header file has nothing to do with linking. The `exp()` function is still there in the library, and will be linked to.

*However*, with no definition of `exp()` from the header file, it will default to taking whatever type argument you give it, and returning an `int` value. Which is not what the library function returns and possibly not what it takes, and why you are getting odd results. If you add `double exp(double);` after the include, it will work as you expect.

You should have gotten a warning about the undefined function. Don't ignore those! (Or don't turn them off.) The warnings are there for a reason. This is the reason.

Comment: To clarify this answer:  unlike C++,  C *allows* you to odr-use a function without a prototype, or have a prototype without argument list, that's why we had to write  `void foo(void)`, not `void foo()`. Compiler not obliged to diagnose it (and MSVC apparently doesn't on some settings), it's up to developer to ensure that program can be linked correctly.

Comment: *with no definition of `exp()` from the header file, it will default to taking an `int` argument ...*  I'm not sure about that - I think offhand all arguments will undergo default argument promotions and be passed as if the function were a varargs one.

Comment: @AndrewHenle that's right, C default argument promotions.  One can declare `void foo()` and then call `foo(3, 4.2);` compiler would assume  that there is somewhere `void foo(int, double)`. In C++ we're forced to use `...` and cannot have it without a fixed argument in front of `...`. A decent cost for having functional polymorphism - overloads

Comment: You are absolutely right. It appears without `-W3` MSVC2019 does not emit the C4013 "undefined, assuming extern returning int" warning. I expected that one to be in the default warning level. I should have known better to include all warning levels.

Comment: You are absolutely right. That certainly _should_ be included in the default warning level. Figures. Microsoft.